# Why everyone can see my Graphite data?

Tags: django, .htaccess, metrics, graphite, whisper

Recently I installed Graphite to monitor my application.

I installed it on an external (cloud) server and used the following configuration:

**local_settings.py:**

```
USE_REMOTE_USER_AUTHENTICATION = True
DASHBOARD_REQUIRE_AUTHENTICATION = True
DASHBOARD_REQUIRE_PERMISSIONS = True
```

Everything works fine, and I can send data using Graphite plugins, and read the data using browser, except that the metrics are public and it is not required to login.

Also I used `htaccess` but it is not good enough (because there is no simple way to implement logout in Graphite)

I couldn't find how to enforce user authentication before presenting data.